# Directory does not meet Test-Path $item -PathType Container

Tags: powershell

According to [this website](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730955.aspx), every folder should be a container and thus should meet the following condition:

```
if (Test-Path $item -PathType Container) 
{
    "TRUE: " + $item.Name
} 
else 
{ 
    "FALSE: " + $item.Name
}
```

But for me that is not true, some folders are true while others are false. This is my whole script:

```
function GetFiles($path = $pwd) 
{ 
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {
        $item;
        if (Test-Path $item -PathType Container) 
        {
            "TRUE: " + $item.Name
            GetFiles $item.FullName
        } 
        else 
        { 
            "FALSE: " + $item.Name
        }
    } 
}
```

Why is the function returning false sometimes?

**UPDATE:** For example, this is a case I would expect it to be true:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
----                -------------     ------ ----
d----         9/10/2013   1:51 PM            Assets
FALSE: Assets
```

Comment: They could be shortcuts to folders and not necessarily containers themselves.

Comment: @EricLeschinski If I print $item before asking it is shown as a directory. I will be adding a sample to the question.

Comment: Maybe the program you are using does not have read access to the directory.  So you can see it, but you can't determine whether or not it is a container?  Can you show the permissions on the files that are containers and not containers?

Comment: @EricLeschinski Permissions look completely the same. My user as well as Administrators have full access. Even running the script from an elevated command prompt doesn't change the output.

Comment: Could there be spaces, symbols or other bad characters in the filepath so that the -pathType is testing `C:\my` instead of `C:\my file\blah`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$item.FullName` is required ;)

```
function GetFiles($path = $pwd) 
{ 
    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path)
    {
        if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $item.FullName -PathType Container)
        {
            "TRUE: " + $item.Name
            GetFiles $item.FullName
        } 
        else 
        { 
            "FALSE: " + $item.Name
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of PowerShell are you using ?

With PowerShell V3 you can try :

```
Get-ChildItem $path -Directory
```

Using PowerShell V2 I still use

```
Get-ChildItem | where {$_.psIscontainer -eq $true}
```

In your case

```
if ($item.psIscontainer -eq $true) 
{
    "TRUE: " + $item.Name
} 
else 
{ 
    "FALSE: " + $item.Name
}
```